# Decoding Byte Array to String in Swift (working with Bluetooth)

Tags: android, swift, byte

I am trying to convert a byte array to a String in Swift. I have an example of how the decoding works in Android. However, since I am new to Swift, I am having problems in translating this.
Here is the Android code snippet:

```
private String packageHead = null;
private byte numberPackages = 0;
private ArrayList<byte[]> usageData = null;

if (BluetoothLEService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
    final byte[] txValue = intent.getByteArrayExtra(BluetoothLEService.EXTRA_DATA);

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

            if(packageHead == null){
                packageHead = txValue[0] + "";
                numberPackages = txValue[1];
                usageData = new ArrayList<byte[]>(numberPackages);
            }
            if(packageHead.equals(txValue[0] + "")){
                usageData.add(txValue[2], getUsageData(txValue));
            }

            boolean transmissionDone = (usageData.size() == numberPackages);

            if(transmissionDone){
                packageHead = null;
                processBluetoothPackages(usageData);
                usageData = null;
            }

    }
});

}

private byte[] getUsageData(byte[] txValue) {
    byte[] ret = new byte[txValue.length - 3];
    for(int i = 0; i < ret.length; ++i){
        ret[i] = txValue[i+3];
    }

    return ret;
}

private void processBluetoothPackages(List<byte[]> usageDataParam) {

    int size = 0;
    for (byte[] arr : usageDataParam) {
        size += arr.length;
    }
    byte[] usageDataArr = new byte[size];
    int index = 0;
    for (byte[] arr : usageDataParam) {
        for(byte b : arr){
            usageDataArr[index] = b;
            ++index;
        }
    }

    String text = new String(usageDataArr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

}
};
```

The byte array to be decoded is [170, 2, 0, 104, 116, 116, 112, 58, 47, 47, 119, 119, 119, 46, 97, 100, 101, 115, 115, 111].
My problem in Swift is that there seems to be many packages inside the byte array which I have to decode. And I am not able to reach them as in Android.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Update:

I am trying to use the Swift technologies. However, I only get "nil" as a result. All the tips I have tried, lead to the same result.

```
    let data = characteristic.value;
    let values = [UInt8](data!);

    var dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8);
    print("Raw data: \(String(describing: values))");
    print("String data: \(String(describing: values))");
```

The result is:
Raw data: [170, 2, 0, 104, 116, 116, 112, 58, 47, 47, 119, 119, 119, 46, 97, 100, 101, 115, 115, 111]
String data: nil

Comment: Can you *explain* how the data is structured?

Comment: I just got an email from the bluetooth company, telling me that the first two items of the array are not part of what has to be decoded. When I decoded with the code I wrote above, leaving out the first two items, everything worked fine.